# jquerytools overlay with dynamic size (width, height)

Tags: overlay, jquery-tools

Using [jquerytools' overlay plugin (the apple style)](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/).

The problem is that the background of the verlay ([this static image](http://jquerytools.org/media/img/overlay/transparent.png)), and its content are in **fixed size**.

How can the size of the overlay be dynamically changed according to content coming from ajax?

Also if you look at their own example at http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html, you can see that there is a static size for the overlay.

What if the contents of the external page were less that the predefined size?

Another problem related is that the scroll bar is shown even if content's height is less than container's height.